# Custom Jquery Slideshow

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my example and code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/6j4cT/3/

There is too much code for me to paste here so it's easier if you all refer to the link above.

My issue is that on load the jquery is not inserting the class "active" on the first "li" within #news-items.

Secondly I am  wanting to change the transition to a fade rather than a hide / show transition.

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You may use `fadeOut` function to change the transition to a fade

```
$(function(){
    $('.slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.slideshow :first-child').fadeOut(2000).next('img').fadeIn(2000).end().appendTo('.slideshow');}, 4000);
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/azizasm/5FWMt/)

credit for this code should goes to http://davealger.info